# Compiler javac11 is not recognizing onMethod_ property when upgrading Hibernate version from 5 to 6

Tags: java, hibernate, lombok

Basically when I change the Hibernate version in the `pom.xml` file of my project (I'm using JDK 11 and Maven 3.9.x).

From this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

To this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

By compiling the project, the compiler is showing me two failures in some Model classes (that uses some jpa annotations and Lombok annotations to create `getter` and `setter` methods), as in:

```
[ERROR] /Users/daniel.henao/Documents/CAM_Projects/compass-platform-api/compass-data/compass-data-relational/src/main/java/com/rebelai/compass/data/relational/models/CreativeAsset.java:[81,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class __
  location: class com.rebelai.compass.data.relational.models.CreativeAsset
```

```
[ERROR] /Users/daniel.henao/Documents/CAM_Projects/compass-platform-api/compass-data/compass-data-relational/src/main/java/com/rebelai/compass/data/relational/models/CreativeAsset.java:[113,13] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method onMethod_()
  location: @interface lombok.Getter
```

The entity is something like:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE creative_asset SET deleted = 1,account_id = null,advertiser_id = null WHERE id = ?")
@Table(name = "creative_asset")
@Where(clause = "deleted <> 1")
public class CreativeAsset implements Serializable {

private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getFormatterLogger();
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1518063282136024146L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    ...

    @Column(name = "orig_entity_id")
    private Long originalEntityId;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "creativeAssets")
    @Getter(onMethod_ = @QueryReference)
    private Set<Creative> creatives = new HashSet<>();
   
    ...

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "secondaryAsset")
    @Getter(onMethod = @__(@QueryReference))
    private Set<Creative> creativesWithSingleSecondaryAsset = new HashSet<>();
}
```

I tried to change this line of code `@Getter(onMethod = @__(@QueryReference))` to this `@Getter(onMethod_ = @QueryReference)` since the Lombok documentation says that on javac8 and up, one must add an underscore after `onMethod` (This is the documentation [text](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/onX)